# Python 3: How do i start 2 processes return the answer from whichever finishes first, and stop the other process early

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, concurrency, multiprocess

I have two algorithms A and B. Both algorithms take the same string as an input, perform the same transformation on the string, and return a new string.

The transformation performed can be very CPU intensive at times, and the algorithms have different approaches to the problem. The algorithms perform drastically different depending on the input string, but I only care about the answer, not which algorithm applies the transformation.

I've written some Psuedo code to explain the problem a little better:

```
def process_alg1(algorithm1, input_string)

    ans_string = algorithm1(input_string)

    q.put(ans_string)

def process_alg2(algorithm2, input_string)

    ans_string = algorithm2(input_string)

    q.put(ans_string)


def apply_transformation(input_string):

    q = multiprocess.Queue()

    process_alg1(input_string)

    process_alg2(input_string)

    final_answer = q.get()

    stop(slowest_process)
```

I'm guessing i need to use daemon processes? I'm just not sure what approach i need to be taking at all. Do i set up a pipeline between processes and some kind of handler that tells the slower process to stop? Can i do this simply with daemons and a queue?

I've found lots of examples for multiple inputs for the same algorithm, but no examples for multiple algorithms working with the same input.

Thanks.

Comment: you would need the main process to periodically poll the child process' `exitcode` attribute to determine if it has terminated yet. then you would have to modify some sort of shared variable that the the other child (or both) periodically check so they know to exit. Sending sigkill is not nice, and doesn't have a direct windows equivelent.

Comment: @Aaron, if i use a daemon process for both and i call this apply_transformation function from another part of my program, will the processes terminate after the apply_transformation call or after the whole program finishes?

Comment: There is no such thing as a dameon process.. only threads

Comment: Is https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.daemon not referring to a daemon process?

Comment: "Additionally, these are not Unix daemons or services, they are normal processes" also I missed the 3.x so my bad (new feature in 3.3).. I still wouldn't trust this, as [how it works] it is platform dependent and windows always had problems for me with zombie processes.

Comment: what if i start both processes but have them timeout after 1 second. would that work for my use case? or is there another way to stop a process without sigkilling it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156616/discussion-between-aaron-and-grant-williams).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a minimal example:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from time import sleep
from numpy.random import randint

def task(n, stopsignal):
    for x in range(n): #complex computation task steps (iterations, etc.. however you break it up)
        with stopsignal.getlock():
            if stopsignal.value: 
                print( mp.current_process().name + " recieved stop signal. Terminating.")
        time.sleep(1) #complex computation
    print( mp.current_process().name + " returned first. attempting to halt others..." )

stopsignal = mp.Value('b', 0, lock=True) #'b' for signed 8 bit int (could use other types)
processes = []
for i in range(5): #start 5 processes
    p = Process(
            target=task, 
            name="Process_{}".format(i), 
            args=(randint(5,20),stopsignal,),
        )
    p.start()
    processes.append(p)

while True:
    with stopsignal.getlock():
        if stopsignal.value:
            break
    for p in processes: #check each process
        if p.exitcode is not None: #will be None until process terminates
            with stopsignal.getlock(): #aquire rlock
                stopsignal.value = 1
            break
    sleep(1) #only check every second
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. Use Pipe instead of Queue:

```
def process_alg1(algorithm1, input_string)

    ans_string = algorithm1(input_string)

    q.put(ans_string)

def process_alg2(algorithm2, input_string)

    ans_string = algorithm2(input_string)

    q.put(ans_string)


def apply_transformation(input_string):

    q = multiprocess.Queue()

    p1 = process_alg1(input_string)

    p2 = process_alg2(input_string)

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    while p1.is_alive() and p2.is_alive():
        print 'Both are still computing' 


    final_answer = q.get()

    stop(p1 if p1.is_alive() else p2)
```

Comment: Ah this is really simple and i love it. What exactly do you mean by use pipe instead of queue though? In the pseudo code it looks like youre still using a queue. Should i swap that out?

Comment: This answer is incomplete and does not stop the child process as the question described. There is no `stop()` function for processes. the closest thing to that would be to lookup the pid and use pcall to sigkill it. There is no real equivelent for windows.

Comment: there is terminate method in multiprocessing module of python which can terminate process. Also it return singal.SIGTERM